# Как спарсить массив строк к нужному типу?

Tags: c#

Пишу метод, который будет получать массив строк и проверять их на некоторые типы, есть идея как реализовать логику, но кажется она не очень удачна. Вот пример моего кода:

```
private Type GetColumnType(List<string> columns)
{
    int matches = 0;
    foreach (var col in columns)
    {
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(col, out var res))
            break;
        else
            matches++;
    }
    if (matches == columns.Count)
        return typeof(DateTime);
}
```

Идея в том что бы проверять сначала на DateTime, потом на int, потом на double. И если ничего из этого не получится оставлять строку.

Мне не нравится, что получается простыня if'ов. Может быть, есть какая то идея по-лучше?

Answer (score 2):

```
bool areAllDateTime = columns.Any(x => !DateTime.TryParse(x, out _));
```

И т.д.

Comment: Спасибо. Но TryParse принимает 2 аргумента. Сделал DateTime.TryParse(x, out _)

Comment: Так же, Any возвращает true если хотя бы один элемент соответствует условию

Comment: @banana там отрицание

Comment: @aepot 
`var columns = new List<string>() { "123", "32", "asd" };
bool areAllDateTime = columns.Any(x => !int.TryParse(x, out _));
Console.WriteLine(areAllDateTime);`
Выводит в консоль **"True"**. Нужно использовать **All** или исправить именование переменной)

Comment: @banana `columns.All(x => int.TryParse(x, out _))` попробуйте